# PHP - Session variables are being deleted after POST

Tags: php, session, post

I have this problem: I have a HTML form for add new users with some fields; the more important ones are nick and password. When I complete the fields, I submit and all works fine (the new user appears in database, too).

However, after that, I lost my SESSION variables. I know that because I call them at first of each page to know if a correct user is logged. I think the error is produced by nick and password fields. Is it possible that PHP, Chrome or whatever is interpreting form nick and password as logged user nick and password, and that's the reason why SESSION variables are crashed?

Thank you.

---

EDIT: there is part of the code:

Form:

```
<input type="text" name="user" required />
<input type="password" name="pass" required />
<input type="submit" name="add_user" />
```

There were the two inputs. Very simple. A basic form, with a submit that redirects to a PHP page, that works with the POST data:

```
if(isset($_POST["add_user"])){

$nick=$_POST["user"];
$password=$_POST["pass"];

$query="insert into users(nick,password) 
values('$nick','$password')";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);}
```

After that, SESSION vars aren't working. I have $_SESSION['login'], $_SESSION['password'] and a few more, and they are created with the login. But, after add a new user, they disappeared.

I printed my session_vars, and I confirmed that they disappeared after the POST.

### ----------------------------------------------------

OK, I solved it. It was an error of user privileges comprobation. The code was fine, after all (at least this part). Thank you all, anyway.

Comment: Can you post some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Check to see where you set these values and (if possible) set a debug point, or at least generate some output to see when it's actually called and with what.  Try adding a `print_r($_SESSION);` to see what values are held.

Comment: session_start(); ... On every page before used to

Comment: You say `SESSION['login']` - you are using `$_SESSION['login']` aren't you!

Comment: I have session_start() on all of that pages. And I am using $_SESSION, don't worry for that.

Comment: please add your full code .. so i can easily help you'

Answer (score 0):

> html **Page1.php**

```
<input type="text" name="user" required />
<input type="password" name="pass" required />
<input type="submit" name="add_user" />
```

> php

```
// Start the session
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["add_user"])){

$nick=$_POST["user"];
$password=$_POST["pass"];

$query="insert into users(nick,password) 
values('$nick','$password')";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);}


$_SESSION["user"] =  $nick;
$_SESSION["pass"] = $password;
```

**NOTE:** **Page2.php**

Now You Can Use Session on Every Page Just Added First on the top of php code:

```
    session_start();  

echo $_SESSION["user"];
echo $_SESSION["pass"];
```